# How to use Google API Client Library for JavaScript (gapi) with async/await?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, google-api

I have a Vue 3 / Quasar / TypeScript app that is using the [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) (also known as gapi).

All the official code examples use a convoluted mess of callbacks. Instead, I want to implement it using async/await.

I found [this tutorial](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-gapi-the-google-drive-client-and-the-file-picker/#load-the-gapi) which has given me a head start. But I'm struggling to implement it.

As per the tutorial I put this in the `<head>` of my `index.template.html`:

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="window.gapiLoaded()"
      onerror="window.gapiLoadError(event)"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="q-app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I then combine other parts of the tutorial into my own `loadGooglePeopleApi` function. This is placed inside a Vue composable, and called within a single file component (SFC):

```
export const loadGooglePeopleApi = async (accessToken: string) => {
  // Wait for the defered gapi script tag to finish loading
  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    window.gapiLoaded = res;
    window.gapiLoadError = rej;
  });
  // Load Google API Client Library (aka gapi)
  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gapi.load('client', { callback: res, onerror: rej });
  });
  // Load an interface for the Google People API
  await gapi.client.load('https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest');
  // Set the access_token
  gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: accessToken });
};
```

Unfortunatley it produces some TypeScript errors because those types do not exist on `window`:

```
Property 'gapiLoaded' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. ts(2339)
Property 'gapiLoadError' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. ts(2339)
```

So I added the types like so:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    gapiLoaded?: (value: unknown) => void;
    gapiLoadError?: (reason?: any) => void;
  }
}
```

But now I am getting this error in the console whenever the page loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.gapiLoaded is not a function
```

Am I implementing this correctly? Why do I get the console error?

Comment: I have same problem =/